# How to edit Rails serialized hashes in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model in my Rails app for a Bulletin, and when it is created, a lot of the values are stored in the database as serialized hashes or arrays, to be accessed later. I'm trying to create an edit view for just one of those hashes, but I can't figure out how to access it in my form.

The hash looks like this when stored:

```
top_offices = { first_office: "Office Name", first_office_amount: 1234.50, 
second_office: "Office Name", second_office_amount: 1234.50 }
```

And so on... there are five offices.

So in the console I can edit the values by doing:

```
bulletin = Bulletin.last
bulletin.top_offices[:first_office] = "New Office"
bulletin.top_offices[:first_office_amount] = 1234.00
bulletin.save
```

I can't figure out how to make a form that allows me to assign those values properly. I don't even actually need the form to populate with the previously stored values because I'm changing them completely any time I use the form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1: Single instance method to update serialized attribute

As far as I know it's not possible to edit directly from a form a serialized attribute.

When I have this kind of things I'm always creating an instance method in the model that receive params and do the update (Could also do the save if I end the method name with a bang (!)).

In your case I would do the following:

```rb
class Bulletin

  ...

  def update_top_offices!(params)
    params.each do |key, value|
      self.top_offices[key] = value
    end

    self.save
  end

  ...
end
```

## Option 2: A getter/setter per serialized attribute keys

Also another possibility if you really want to use a form to update the serialized attribute is to create a getter/setter as following:

```rb
class Bulletin

  ...

  def first_office
    self.top_offices[:first_office]
  end

  def first_office=(value)
    self.top_offices[:first_office] = value
  end

  ...
end
```

But then don't forget to save updated values.

## Options 3: Overriding method_missing

A last possibility is to override `method_missing` but it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Okay. I think I'll be able to figure it out using option one. I probably prefer the second approach but I can't figure out how it works in my head. How do I use those methods in the form? Can I just make a `form_tag` and some `text_field_tag`'s for `:first_office` and so on, once I define those, and submit to my update action?

Comment: The *_field view helpers are looking for the given attribute name to the object given form_for. So if you did `form_for @bulletin do |f|` and then you do `f.text_field :first_office` then the `text_field` helper will call something named `first_office` on the object. It could be an attribute or a method. That's the "magic" part ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example which just iterates over the existing key/value pairs in top_offices and generates form fields for them.

```
<% @bulletin.top_offices.each do |key, value| %>
  <input name="bulletin[top_offices][<%= key %>]" type="text" value="<%= value %>" />
<% end %>
```

Will generate:

```
<input name="bulletin[top_offices][first_office]" ... />
<input name="bulletin[top_offices][first_office_amount]" ... />
# etc.
```

If you don't trust your users then you may want to do a sanity check on values submitted for top_offices.